# Upload to localhost with ssh, locked account

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, ftp

I can access the files on localhost in my FTP programme, but the account is locked, so while I can see them and view localhost in my browser, I can not edit, download or upload any files.

I setup ssh with the following positive results as explained on http://www.unixtutorial.org/2009/05/ubuntu-ssh-how-to-enable-secure-shell-in-ubuntu/ before that I couldn't even access localhost in my ftp programme.

```
ssh localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is ce:12:ab:b4:e6:02:03:de:35:82:22:bd:63:f5:9a:d1.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
simon@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 13.04 (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-27-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Sun Jul 14 11:57:29 2013
```

I tried:

```
$ scp test.bin simon@server:/tmp
```

Which results in a timeout

but

```
ssh localhost
```

logs me in with a password.

This learning curve is amazing, I love Ubuntu.

[image: preview]
[image: options]

If anyone has any ideas, could you indulge me and point me in the right direction please?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking about. Apparently, you can log in with ssh, so where is the problem? The secure options you are highlighting are for key-based authentication (rather than password-based authentication), but you don't need them if you can log in just with your password.

Comment: @January Sorry about that, I have changed the image to that which shows the locked symbol.

Comment: Now I'm confused (and I don't know your FTP program). Do you want to connect with ssh/sftp or ftp? (those are two very different protocols, and I'd highly recommend sftp). Which one does not work? What does "locked" mean? (there is no such thing; you can view the files, therefore you have logged in; whether you have write permissions is another thing) Why are you logging in as root?

Comment: OK I tried logging in as root because the www folder is owned by root it also works the same if I login with simon and my password. The choices I am offered by CrossFTP Pro ha

Comment: missed the end off Sorry ...ve been added to the question.

Comment: So okey, choose SFTP/SSH as the one that is (i) secure and (ii) allows you to log in (although I'm not sure whether ssh will allow the *root* to log in!). Provide your username and password. Before trying `/var/www` go to `/tmp` and see whether you can create files there.

Comment: I have just logged in with my username and password and navigated to /var/tmp where I could create a folder, but not transfer files, next I returned to /var/www and there I was unable to create a folder or upload. This seems to be pointing towards permissions or owners. What should the owner/chmod settings be for the www folder?

Comment: Please try to create files in `/tmp` as instructed.

Comment: When I did that, the connection dropped

Answer (score 1):

OK, there is already way too much for a single comment. Let's untangle the confused discussion. There are two problems here: (i) access and (ii) permissions on the server.

1. FTP vs SFTP. Although the names are similar and both "things" look very much alike, these two ways of accessing your server are handled by two very different programs.

   - FTP is run by an FTP server; it is both old and simple
   - SFTP on the other hand is run by an SSH server and over an SSH connection. It is more versatile and more secure. You will be well advised to access your web server using SSH/SFTP.
   - you can use SSH both to connect directly to the server, log in and run commands, as well as run SFTP just for transferring the files. Heck, you can even mount the server like a network drive using SSH!
2. Testing the SFTP connection. If you can log in as `simon`, you should be able to transfer files to and from `/tmp` and `/home/simon`. If this doesn't work with your program, please open a terminal and type

   ```
   # create a fake file for testing
   dd if=/dev/zero of=test.bin count=128
   scp test.bin simon@server:/tmp
   scp test.bin simon@server:/home/simon
   ```

   If these work (as they should), then your problems are either due to your ftp program, or due to permissions on the server.
3. Once you are logged in and gained access to the server, but can't modify the files you wish to modify, you might want to log in with ssh first to look around what is happening. Open a terminal, and type

   ```
   ssh simon@localserver
   ```

   Enter password, log in and try to create and modify files, and look who the files belong to:

   ```
   touch /tmp/test
   touch /var/www/test
   ls -l /var/www
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I type in the commands you agve in to the Terminal window, everything stops at `scp test.bin simon@server:/tmp`

Comment: I get `ssh: connect to host server port 22: Connection timed out lost connection` after about 3 minutes

Comment: Can you do `ssh simon@server`? If not, maybe you don't have an ssh server enabled on the server side? If not, read http://www.unixtutorial.org/2009/05/ubuntu-ssh-how-to-enable-secure-shell-in-ubuntu/

Comment: No, the same result: `ssh: connect to host localserver port 22: Connection timed out` I'll start reading :)

Comment: I had read this before and followed the instructions to install setup and test the ssh server. It worked then as it does now, but The terminal command `scp test.bin simon@server:/tmp` and the CrossFTP programme, still do not work.

Comment: So what command *does* work?

Comment: `ssh localhost` works as does `ps -aef | grep sshd` giving the exact same responses as the tutorial described, except that this time it didn't ask for my password, I already did that yesterday. I have just tried creating a folder in /var again and, as well as creating the folder, I also managed to up load a file to it, but the www folder still resists.

Comment: But you still cannot connect to the server from your client machine? (ssh simon@server or scp test.bin simon@server:/tmp)

Comment: no, still comes back with `ssh: connect to host server port 22: Connection timed out lost connection` It has to be something silly, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: To add insult to injury, I have just managed to successfully transfer and edit files by logging in as root with ip address of 127.0.1.1 It's working, but I don't know for how long!